# How low potassium can potatoes have due to low potassium in soil?

Tags: plant-physiology, soil, minerals

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato#Comparison_to_other_staple_foods) 100 grams of potatoes has 2005 milligrams of potassium.

But if there is low potassium in the soil where it grows, it may not be able to acquire so much potassium.

How little of potassium can a healthy-looking potato have?

Comment: Do you have any reference that suggests potato potassium concentration is appreciably affected at all by soil potassium? My naive expectation would be that low potassium in the soil would primarily stunt growth, as this is what generally happens with plants more generally.

Comment: @BryanKrause no, i do not have references. i think some molecules are acquired if they are present, not if they are not. i think, potatoes have relatively much of potassium, so they may gather it in amounts much more than it is required for their growth.